# Admin Console displaying 500 server error on re-enabling project

Tags: google-app-engine

I was trying to re-enable a project I disabled on the AppEngine Admin Console. I went to 'Application Settings', 'Disable Application', and I clicked on re-enable application now, but It will throw this error message.

```
Server Error

A server error has occurred

*Return to Applications screen.*
```

It will also throw this message even if I try to delete, disable, re-enable any other projects I have. Any fix on this?

Comment: What do you mean by 'disabling and re-enabling a project' ? Are you referring to deleting and restoring a project ?

Comment: No. On the old app engine console, After I disable a project. I tried to re-enable the project. This is not on the new google developers console.

Comment: Hey, 'disable a project' on old app engine console is the same thing as 'deleting a project' on the new Google Developers Console. Can you go to the new console at https://console.developers.google.com and check if your project is still inside 'Projects pending deletion'?

Comment: @Jun Nope. Its not on it.

Comment: Hey, I am able to reproduce your issue. Basically this is the second time I tried to disable my project. Then I try to re-enable it after I disabled it, and I am getting the same error you mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the error you're experiencing, but the app is actually re-enabled although it showed the server error after I tried twice to re-enable it. I think as long as you keep trying to re-enable it, it would finally be enabled again as expected.

Comment: Thank you. I tried your instructions. and it worked. :)